# Biblatex-chicago book title and contribution name duplication

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I am using material from several books in a series. All the books are edited by the same person (here Huot), who as it happens contributions in each book whose names are the same (here "Preface").

Another author has contributions in each volume.

As I understand the documentation, `booktitle` (etc.) should be used for the book when it contains individual named contributions by a variety of authors, while `title` (etc.) should be used for the contributions.

The MWE below illustrates this situation and problems I have encountered:

1. Footnotes 2 and 4 abbreviate the book in which the contributions appear in the same way. One can argue that it isn't ambiguous here since the flow is clear, but in my main work that is not the case, and regardless, one doesn't wish to tax the reader with having to horse around following the flow
2. One can certainly use `longcrossref` to make it unambiguous, but that makes for seriously turgid footnotes when the books have many fields (most omitted here for MWE); this solution is overkill
3. One can get around this by dispensing with `crossref` and repeating only the desired fields in the entry, but that goes counter to the whole purpose of having citations built automatically....
4. The bibliography for the last two items is incomplete, with or without the `crossref` feature.

I assume I'm overlooking something here or going about it the wrong way?

(Side note: citing one or the other preface later one can be dealt with, I've found, by giving a `shorttitle` which disambiguates (and is in fact longer!), e.g. `shortitle = {Preface (1)}` etc.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Book1,
    Booksubtitle = {sub one},
    Booktitle = {Book One},
    Editor = {J.-L. Huot},
    Series={Series},
    Number = {1},
    Publisher = {Publisher},
    Location={Location},
    Series = {Series},
    Titleaddon = {title add-on 1},
    Year = {2001}}

@inbook{Huot:preface1,
    Author = {J.-L. Huot},
    Crossref = {Book1},
    Pages = {101--199},
    Title = {Preface}}

@inbook{Arnaud:catalogue1,
    Author = {D. Arnaud},
    Crossref = {Book1},
    Pages = {201--299},
    Title = {Catalogue One},
    subtitle={subtitle one}}

@book{Book2,
    Booksubtitle = {sub two},
    Booktitle = {Book Two},
    Editor = {J.-L. Huot},
    Series={Series},
    Number = {2},
    Publisher = {Publisher},
    Location={Location},
    Series = {Series},
    Titleaddon = {title add-on 2},
    Year = {2001}}

@inbook{Huot:preface2,
    Author = {J.-L. Huot},
    Crossref = {Book2},
    Pages = {111--119},
    Title = {Preface}}

@inbook{Arnaud:catalogue2,
    Author = {D. Arnaud},
    Crossref = {Book2},
    Pages = {222--229},
    Title = {Catalogue Two},
    subtitle={subtitle two}}
    \end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=british,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    language=british
    ]{biblatex-chicago}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
Introductory sentence.\footcite[1]{Huot:preface1} Some other stuff.\footnote{\cite{Arnaud:catalogue1}. The same article can also be found elsewhere.}

Bla bla bla.

Introductory sentence.\footcite[2]{Huot:preface2} Some other stuff.\footnote{\cite{Arnaud:catalogue2}. The same article can also be found elsewhere.}
\backmatter
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output clips:

[image: clip of footnote problem][image: clip of bibliography problem]

Comment: You *probably* also want to use `@incollection` instead of `@inbook` and `@collection` instead of `@book`. The rule of thumb is: If a book has an editor (and no author) it is probably a `@collection`, if it has an author it's probably a `@book`. If you are really citing the preface it might well be a `@suppcollection` instead of an `@incollection`.

Comment: Addendum: With `biblatex-chicago` `@suppcollection` does not seem to give good results, so scrap that. The difference between `@incollection` and `@inbook` should normally be virtually non-existent.

Comment: @moewe Just seen. Good to know, noted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `crossref` the `Title` field of the `@book` entry is automatically mapped to the `Booktitle` field of the `@inbook` entry (and so on). This means, that you should use `Title` rather than `Booktitle` in the parent entries:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Book1,
    Subtitle = {sub one},
    Title = {Book One},
    Editor = {J.-L. Huot},
    Series={Series},
    Number = {1},
    Publisher = {Publisher},
    Location={Location},
    Series = {Series},
    Titleaddon = {title add-on 1},
    Year = {2001}}

@inbook{Huot:preface1,
    Author = {J.-L. Huot},
    Crossref = {Book1},
    Pages = {101--199},
    Title = {Preface}}

@inbook{Arnaud:catalogue1,
    Author = {D. Arnaud},
    Crossref = {Book1},
    Pages = {201--299},
    Title = {Catalogue One},
    subtitle={subtitle one}}

@book{Book2,
    Subtitle = {sub two},
    Title = {Book Two},
    Editor = {J.-L. Huot},
    Series={Series},
    Number = {2},
    Publisher = {Publisher},
    Location={Location},
    Series = {Series},
    Titleaddon = {title add-on 2},
    Year = {2001}}

@inbook{Huot:preface2,
    Author = {J.-L. Huot},
    Crossref = {Book2},
    Pages = {111--119},
    Title = {Preface}}

@inbook{Arnaud:catalogue2,
    Author = {D. Arnaud},
    Crossref = {Book2},
    Pages = {222--229},
    Title = {Catalogue Two},
    subtitle={subtitle two}}
    \end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=british,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    language=british,
    ]{biblatex-chicago}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
Introductory sentence.\footcite[1]{Huot:preface1} Some other stuff.\footnote{\cite{Arnaud:catalogue1}. The same article can also be found elsewhere.}

Bla bla bla.

Introductory sentence.\footcite[2]{Huot:preface2} Some other stuff.\footnote{\cite{Arnaud:catalogue2}. The same article can also be found elsewhere.}

\backmatter
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

You can see what happens, if you run biber in tool mode on your bib-file:

```
biber --tool --output-resolve-crossrefs
```

Comment: Ah, I see. That was not clear to me at all, even after several attempts to peruse the documentation. Seems to work like a charm now!